# Intellij not recognize sparksession sparkcontext sqlcontext- Spark version 2.4.4

Tags: maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am creating Maven project in Intellij with spark and scala.**But Intellij failed to recognise sparksession,  sparkcontext and sqlcontext.** Image attached herewith.

**Error: Cannot resolve symbol getsqlcontext
Error: Cannot resolve symbol getSparkContaxt**

My Understanding about POM is A Project Object Model or POM is the fundamental unit of work in Maven. It is an XML file that contains information about the project and configuration details used by Maven to build the project.

Do i need to change something in POM Properties or dependency.

My POM file looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.IPM</groupId>
    <artifactId>lambda</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>spark-lambda</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <spark.version>2.4.4</spark.version>
        <chill.version>0.7.2</chill.version>
        <algebird.version>0.11.0</algebird.version>
        <kafka.clients.version>0.8.2.1</kafka.clients.version>
        <avro.version>1.7.7</avro.version>
        <spark-cassandra-connector.version>1.6.1</spark-cassandra-connector.version>
        <cassandra-driver-core.version>3.0.1</cassandra-driver-core.version>
        <nscala-time.version>2.6.0</nscala-time.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
            <artifactId>config</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark-cassandra-connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>${cassandra-driver-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.nscala-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>nscala-time_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${nscala-time.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka.clients.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
            <artifactId>chill_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${chill.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
            <artifactId>chill-avro_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${chill.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
            <artifactId>algebird-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${algebird.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <!-- provided -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka.clients.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <!-- provided -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <!-- provided -->
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <!-- provided -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <!-- provided -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-convert</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>*:*</include>
                                </includes>
                            </artifactSet>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>




</project>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liUP4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no such functions in the Spark, you need to create context correctly, like this (here is the [full example](https://github.com/alexott/dse-playground/blob/master/spark-oss/src/main/scala/com/datastax/alexott/spark/JoinTestsScala.scala)):

```scala
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val sc = new SparkContext()
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sc.getConf).getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

  ...
  }
```

2nd, you dependencies are incorrect - you're using Spark Cassandra Connector 1.6.1 that is designed for Spark 1.6, while you're trying to use Spark 2.4.4.

You need to use Spark Cassandra Connector 2.5.0 (the latest) - it's compatible with Spark 2.4, and also has [a lot of new functionality](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2020/05/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all).

You also need to delete this dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
   <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
   <version>${cassandra-driver-core.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and most probably this:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
   <artifactId>config</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you want to use Spark with Kafka, you need to use correct package, for example:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

And here you can [find an example](https://github.com/alexott/dse-playground/blob/master/spark-dse/src/main/scala/com/datastax/alexott/streaming/StructuredStreamingKafkaDSE.scala) of using Kafka + Spark + Cassandra.

Comment: You have too many dependencies, imho. Start small. Grab things from https://github.com/alexott/dse-playground/blob/master/spark-oss/pom.xml - it’s working project... just clone repo, copy Pom.xml from it, slightly adjust versions to use SCC 2.5.0